# Handling large grid datasets in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, extjs, sproutcore

What are some of the better solutions to handling large datasets (100K) on the client with JavaScript. In particular, if you have multi-column sort and search capabilities, how do you handle fetching (and pre-fetching) the data, client side model binding (for display), and caching the data.

I would imagine a good solution would be doing some thoughtful work in the background. For instance, initially, if the table was displaying N items, it might fetch 2N items, return the data for the user, and then go fetch the next 2N items in the background (even if the user hasn't requested this). As the user made search/sort changes, it would throw out (or maybe even cache the initial base case), and do similar functionality.

Can you share the best solutions you have seen?

Thanks

Comment: Do you think displaying 100k rows to a user is a good user experience?

Comment: @jfar: if the user has asked for 100k rows, then **yes**, absolutely show them.  I used a product in the past which arbitrarily limited its data grid display to 2,000 records, which was *incredibly* frustrating.

Comment: @josh3736 > 2000 != 100,000, could a human reasonably parse through 100k records to perform any meaningful activity?

Comment: @jfar: In the particular case I was talking about, I would be looking at the results of a query I had built. If I simply wanted to scan through the list of results (whether 2,500 or 100,000 records) to spot check them (as a way make sure my query was correct), I was SOL. There are many times it is useful to be able to see your entire dataset, even if you're not necessarily "parsing" each and every record. Bottom line: don't limit your users based on your own assumptions; everyone works differently.

Comment: I get your point.  I'm talking about the maximum cognitive load placed on an individual.  With your logic we should give them management studio and teach them how SELECT * FROM table works. ;)

Comment: Who said anything about displaying 100k rows? That is what the N is for, as in show N rows of the 100K available.

Answer (score 3):

Use a jQuery table plugin like DataTables:  http://datatables.net/

It supports server-side processing for sorting, filtering, and paging.  And it includes pipelining support to prefetch the next x pages of records:  http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html

Actually the DataTables plugin works 4 different ways:
1.  With an HTML table, so you could send down a bunch of HTML and then have all the sorting, filtering, and paging work client-side.
2.  With a JavaScript array, so you could send down a 2D array and let it create the table from there.
3.  Ajax source - which is not really applicable to you.
4.  Server-side, where you send data in JSON format to an empty table and let DataTables take it from there.

Answer (score 3):

[SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki) does exactly what you're looking for.  ([Demo](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples))

Using the AJAX data store, SlickGrid can handle millions of rows without flinching.

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged this with Ext JS, I'll point you to [Ext.ux.LiveGrid](http://www.ext-livegrid.com/) if you haven't already seen it.  The source is available, so you might have a look and see how they've addressed this issue.  This is a popular and widely-used extension in the Ext JS world.

With that said, I personally think (virtually) loading that much data is useless as a user experience.  Manually pulling a scrollbar around (jumping hundreds of records per pixel) is a far inferior experience to simply typing what you want.  I'd much prefer some robust filtering/searching instead of presenting that much data to the user.

What if you went to Google and instead of a search box, it just loaded the entire internet into one long virtual list that you had to scroll through to find your site... :)

Comment: +1 for pointing out the whole 'why would you want to do this' issue

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the data will be used.

For a large dataset, where the browser's Find function was adequate, just returning a straight HTML table was effective. It takes a while to load, but the display is responsive on older, slower clients, and you never have to worry about it breaking.

When the client did the sorting and search, and you're not showing the entire table at once, I had the server send tab-delimited tables through XMLHTTPRequest, parsed them in the browser with list = String.split('\n'), and updated the display with repeated calls to $('node').innerHTML = 'blah'. The JS engine can store long strings pretty efficiently. That ran a lot faster on the client than showing, hiding, and rearranging DOM nodes. Creating and destroying new DOM nodes on the fly turned out to be really slow. Splitting each line into fields on-demand seems to work; I haven't experimented with that degree of freedom.

I've never tried the obvious pre-fetch & background trick, because these other methods worked well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this comprehensive list](http://jspreadsheets.com/) of data grids and 
spreadsheets.

For filtering/sorting/pagination purposes you may be interested in great [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/examples.html?headers), or [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) as a free alternative.

If you need simply display huge list without any additional features [Clusterize.js](https://clusterize.js.org/) should be sufficient.